# JavaScript How to Print A Label in a DIV?

Tags: javascript, html

I have 4 boxes labeled a1, a2, a3, a4 as an example. And when someone clicks on 2 boxes, I want the label (a1, a2 as an example) to print on html output. I just spent over an hour and the best I can come up was printing undefined and null.

Sorry, here is my code

```
HTML
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3" label="a1">
      <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Button 01</a>
      <div class="output"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3" label="a2">
      <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Button 02</a>
      <div class="output"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3" label="a3">
      <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Button 03</a>
      <div class="output"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3" label="a4">
      <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Button 04</a>
      <div class="output"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
const button = document.querySelector('.btn');

button.addEventListener('click', printLabel);

function printLabel(){
  const name = document.querySelector('label');
  const print = document.querySelector('.output');
  print.innerText = name;
}
```

Comment: Please put an example code of what you've already tried even if it doesn't work

Comment: What does "print on html output" mean?

Comment: Like I want to give a div a label of "a1" so when someone clicks that div, text a1 would print on output. Sorry, I am new to JS and doesn't know all the terms

Answer (score 1):

`label` isn't really a standard attribute of the `<div>` tag. You could try `id` if you're just looking for a quick solution. Also, you're accessing everything in a pretty strange way.

1. You should change `label` to `id`. The `id` attribute is pretty much universal to all HTML elements (that I know of) and will allow you to uniquely identify that element.

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3" id="a1">
      <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Button 01</a>
      <div class="output"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3" id="a2">
      <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Button 02</a>
      <div class="output"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3" id="a3">
      <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Button 03</a>
      <div class="output"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3" id="a4">
      <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Button 04</a>
      <div class="output"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

2. Add a unique `id` to all of the `div` elements that are meant to be your "output". This will allow your code to direct the "output" to the right element.

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3" id="a1">
      <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Button 01</a>
      <div class="output" id="a1-output"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3" id="a2">
      <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Button 02</a>
      <div class="output" id="a2-output"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3" id="a3">
      <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Button 03</a>
      <div class="output" id="a3-output"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3" id="a4">
      <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Button 04</a>
      <div class="output" id="a4-output"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

3. Finally, a couple of changes to your JavaScript. The first change you'll see is that I changed `document.querySelector('.btn')` to `document.querySelectorAll('.btn')`. The difference between these methods is that the first one selects ONLY the first element it finds that matches the selector, but the second one selects all elements that match the selector and creates an array.

Next, we loop through that array to add an event listener for each element.

After that, we add a parameter `e` (for event) to the `printLabel()` function because `addEventListener()` passes an event object in the callback function (`printLabel`). This object gives information about the target element related to the event.

Next, we get the target element of the event and that's your `button`. Then we get the `parentElement` of your `button` because your `id` or "label" is on the parent element. Then, you can get the name from the `id` of the parent element.

As a note, remember that `id` attributes CANNOT have spaces or `.` or `#` or really most special characters besides `_`.

Finally, we need to select your "output" element, and we'll use the `id` to do that.

`document.querySelector('#' + name + '-output');` will get the element that has an `id` with the given `name` + `-output`. For example, if you click button `a1` this will get the element with the `id` of `a1-output`. The `#` signifies that you're searching for an `id`.

Now that we stored this element in a variable `print`, we can place the text in it using the `innerHTML` property.

```js
const button = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');
for(var i=0; i < button.length; i++) {
    button[i].addEventListener('click', printLabel);
}

function printLabel(e) {
  var target = e.target;
  var parent = target.parentElement;
  const name = parent.id;
  const print = document.querySelector('#' + name + '-output');
  print.innerHTML = name;
}
```

I created a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lb3djs7x/) to help you.

If you have any questions, please let me know.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed explanation. I console.log each line and understood what you did. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I'm glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

```
    <script>
        function printDiv(divName){
            var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
            var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;

            document.body.innerHTML = printContents;

            window.print();

            document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;

        }
    </script>
<h1> do not print this </h1>

<div id='printMe'>
  Print this only 
</div>

<button onclick="printDiv('printMe')">Print only the above div</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use [event bubbling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_bubbling_and_capture) and [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) to our advantage here. Replace your `label` attribute which is non-standard with a data attribute. Also, don't use `a` if it is not a navigation element, use `button` instead.

```js
//Get the divs
let divs = document.querySelectorAll("[data-label]")

for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++){
  //Add the event listener to the DIVs, yes the divs
  divs[i].addEventListener("click", function(event){
    //Did a button fire the event?
    if(event.target.tagName === "BUTTON"){
      //update the output div in the clicked div
      this.querySelector(".output").innerText = this.dataset.label;
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3" data-label="a1">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button 01</button>
      <div class="output"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3" data-label="a2">
      <button class="btn btn-primary"role="button">Button 02</button>
      <div class="output"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3" data-label="a3">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button 03</button>
      <div class="output"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3" data-label="a4">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button 04</button>
      <div class="output"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

just change your script part to the following to make it work without changing HTML

```
<script>
  //getting all buttons
  var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("btn");
  //adding event listner to all buttons
  for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener("click", printLabel, false);
  }
  function printLabel() {
    const outputDiv = this.parentElement.querySelector(".output"); // this will select only closet div with given class
    outputDiv.innerText = this.parentElement.getAttribute("label");
  }
</script>
```